# Summarizing values for a calculated column

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Good morning all!  Got a head-scratcher this morning, thanks for taking a look.

It's a real pickle but here goes:

Table A has a field by which we assign a numeric value corresponding to a progress state per line, as follows:

0 = Not Started
99 = In Progress
100 = Complete
Each line also has an ID, resulting in something like this:

[image]

The problem to overcome is:

We need another field to summarize the overall progress by ID, but the permutations of complete criteria are unusual.  If all parts are 0, then 0.  If one part is not 0 and the other part is 0, then 99.  If both parts are not 0 and not 100, then 99.  If both parts are 100, then 100.

The last part of this is the the result MUST be in a column, with the end result being:

[image]

I've tried various tricks that have worked for similar things in the past, to no avail this morning.  I think the thing thats getting me is returning the same value on two lines per ID.  Any and all help is very much appreciated, as always thanks to the community for taking a look.

Comment: Why is this tagged Excel?

Comment: I assumed because Excel was the native application from which i leverage PowerPivot that the tag was relevant here.

Comment: Ok - sorry I saw the dax tag and thought you were perhaps in Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the rule is: if all parts are 100 then 100, if all parts are 0 then 0, otherwise 99.

If this is correct, then counting the different statuses per ID could do the job

```
Overall = 
VAR T0 =
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( A ), ALLEXCEPT( A, A[ID] ), A[Progress] = "0" )
VAR T99 =
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( A ), ALLEXCEPT( A, A[ID] ), A[Progress] = "99" )
VAR T100 =
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( A ), ALLEXCEPT( A, A[ID] ), A[Progress] = "100" )
VAR Result =
    IF(
        T0 > 0
            && T99 = 0
            && T100 = 0,
        "0",
        IF( T100 > 0 && T0 = 0 && T99 = 0, "100", "99" )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: here is the code to create A table and the Overall measure https://pastebin.com/3zAD6GMm

Comment: This worked beautifully.  It also provided me with a lesson on variables in DAX, which i was unfamiliar with.  Thank you immensely, i will definitely use this knowledge in the future.